# Orange tree flower blossom

Tags: fruit-trees

Is this normal? Do I have insect problem?

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a bit of a verbal description what exactly you are worried about? The photo is quite blurry...

Comment: I think I can see citrus leaf miner - frequently not a problem.